# Retrieve XML in PHP from jQuery AJAX Request

Tags: php, jquery, xml, ajax

I make jQuery `Ajax` request which return output in `XML` format.
i want to access this `XML` in `PHP` to Process on data.
Below is sample of my code...

getTime.php File

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/xml");

    echo '<Dates>';

    echo '<Now ';
    echo 'val="' . date("h:m:s") . '" ';
    echo '/>';

    echo '</Dates>';
    //echo date("h:m:s");
?>
```

index.php File

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#btnTime').click(function(){
        getData("GetTime.php");
    });
});
function getData(strUrl)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: strUrl,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(output){
                    // I want to Retrieve this XML Object (output) to PHP
        }
    });
}
```

How can I access XML outputed by jQuery in `PHP`?
Please help me..

Comment: the `output` refers to the data returned by the ajax request... did you try it

Comment: You want to send your XML back to PHP?

Comment: post it to another php file.

Comment: yaa.. `output` itself a XMLDocument object.

Comment: Why are you getting it with jQuery if you want to send it back to a PHP file?

Comment: yupp.. i want it back into PHP script.

Comment: then how i do async request from php?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make another call to your webserver in the success callback.

```
function getData(strUrl)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: strUrl,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(output){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: strUrlToPostXml,
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(output){
                    // Whatever you want, the Xml has been successfully posted back to Php
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

But it's quite weird to do that though: it would be much better to have everything done on the  server side using the initial call.

Comment: yaaa.. this is looking weird. I think i have to handle data in jQuery itself.

Comment: but, can i handle those data in jQuery in such a way that i can do server side events on those data?
for e.g. I want to display data in tabular form returned from database by `jQuery Ajax` request and then updation on it.